# Wavesurfer.js works perfectly in Firefox, but not in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, wavesurfer.js

I have a Vue project I am adding wafesurfer.js to. I have gotten it working perfectly with Firefox, but it fails to work in Chrome. I have read about needing to start the `AudioContext` before audio can play, and I have implemented that. Here is my relevant code:

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext
...
initPlayer() {
    this.region = RegionsPlugin.create({resizable:true, drag: true, dragSelection: true})
    
    this.player = WaveSurfer.create({
      container: '#waveform',
      waveColor: '#000000',
      barWidth: 2,
      barHeight: 1,
      barGap: null,
      url: '/test.mp3',
      plugins: [this.region]
  });
},
...
mounted() {
  this.initPlayer()
  this.region.enableDragSelection({resizable: true, drag: true, color: 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)'})
},
...
play() {
    audioContext.resume().then( function() {
       console.log(audioContext.state)
       this.player.play()
       console.log(this.player.isPlaying())
    }.bind(this))
  },
```

Triggered by a `<v-btn @click="play" color="primary">Play Audio</v-btn>`.

I have tried adding a media fallback by adding `backend: 'MediaElement'`, but that didn't help any.

The only warning I get in the console is the warning that the `AudioContext` was not allowed to start, but that's handled by the resume in the `play` method. The `console.log(audioContext.state)` result is `running`. The `console.log(this.player.isPlaying())` result is `false`.

Any suggestions and advice would be most appreciated.